# What is the passive voice of "She quits her teaching job in school"?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

What will be the passive voice for "She quits her teaching job in school"? I have come up with "The teaching job in school is quit by her," but somehow it's not sounding correct. Is it fine?

Comment: *Quit* is a verb that English speakers do not put in passive voice. This might be because it would be confused with the adjective *quit (of)*, which is usually used in phrases such as "I am quit of that trouble", meaning that I no longer have that trouble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Quit* is not really transitive with the noun *job*; it's too intimately linked with its object, and that object is usually an [Object Complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishObjectComplementsSolution.pdf), because the normal meaning is to stop performing some activity permanently, or at least for some time. (There are also [Subject Complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishSubjectComplementsSolution.pdf), but not in this example.)

- *He quit smoking.*

There is also an economic idiom *to quit* which means to stop working at one's employment, permanently and voluntarily (as opposed, for instance, to *being fired*, which is permanent and involuntary, or *being laid off*, which is temporary and involuntary); the only direct object one can *quit* in this idiomatic sense is one's *job*, and so the object is frequently not expressed.

Thus it isn't really a transitive sentence because the verb and its object express an intransitive predicate -- like the idiom *kick the bucket*, meaning 'to die' -- and therefore can't be passivized.

- *Harry kicked the bucket yesterday.* ~ **The bucket was kicked by Harry yesterday.*
- *Harry quit his job yesterday.* ~ **Harry's job was quit by him yesterday.*

Comment: @John Lawler now I got another confusion."He quit smoking" and "He quits smoking" -both are fine?Why we are not adding 's' as 3rd person singular rule?

Comment: @Monojit Because 3SgPres _{-Z}_ is **Present** tense. The principal parts of _quit_ are _quit, quit, quit_. Thus _"He quit smoking"_ is **Past** tense; you can only tell the difference in 3Sg. _"I quit smoking"_ and _"They quit smoking"_ could be either present or past, because they're not inflected for person or number, and the tense inflection is Zero in the case of _quit, hit, shit, bid,_ and [some other _D/T_-final monosyllables](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/strongverbs.htm#Conjugation%2026).

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, "quit" by definition is an active verb; I would switch to something like "The teaching job was vacated." or "The teaching job was abandoned."

One would use the passive voice in this instance, I'd imagine, if you want to put the focus on the job, as opposed to the person who quit the job.

Comment: Well, the [OED3 does attest](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/156786) several instances of *to be quit(ted)* in a passive construction, but most of these are obsolete or apply to a different sense than the one under discussion here.

Answer (score 2):

One way I remember how to use and recognize passive voice is that it often has the effect of "hiding the source". I find it most useful when avoiding blame/credit. Consider:

- (passive) "Your lamp was broken." versus (active) "I broke your lamp."
- (passive) "My code was fixed afterwards." versus (active) "Someone else fixed my code afterwards".

In the case of quitting a job, only the person doing the job can quit it and trying to use passive voice here would sound awkward in my opinion if you tried.