# "Play" as a linking verb?

Tags: verbs

Is the verb "play" used as *a linking verb* in this sentence mentioned below?

> "My younger sister played Tiny Tim in the Christmas performance."

Can a valid argument be made that "played" is synonymous with linking verbs like "became" or "is" in this context?

Comment: No. *Playing* is an actual verb, describing what actors do.

Comment: Thanks...but verbs don't "describe" anything, do they? I'm not trying to be snarky - just precise and grammatically substantive with my explanation.

Comment: It is a transitive verb, with the direct object being the name of the character in the drama that they portray. That's what transitive _play_ means. _Sir Lawrence Olivier played Henry V in the movie_ means that the real person named Sir Lawrence Olivier played the dramatic character "Henry V" when the  real person acted in the movie.

Comment: *Play* is not like *was* because your sister was not Tiny Tim. She was an actress. *Play* here is an ordinary transitive verb and *Tiny Tim* is an example of metonymy (for "the part called Tiny Tim")

Comment: I can understand your reluctance to class this as a transitive construction. Allerton says that surface-transitive constructions like 'The piano had a stool', 'They all had a ball' are better not classed as truly transitive. The passivisability test is often invoked (*'A stool was had by the piano'), but I feel that the nature of DO's should be better explored. I'm grateful that 'A good time was had by all' fails the non-DO test. // 'Play' is certainly linking to an adjective in 'He played possum / dead'.

Comment: The passivisability test mentioned by @Edwin, incidentally, is good evidence that _play_ in this sense **is** a transitive verb with a direct object, because “Tiny Tim was played by my sister” is perfectly good and cromulent. In the sense ‘pretend to be’, however, passivisation fails, and that usage can more meaningfully be called a linking verb: “She played dumb the whole time” => “*Dumb was played by her the whole time”. (“Hard to get was played by her”?!?)

Comment: @Janus If we accept that 'McKellen played Gandalf' say is a transitive construction, 'played the fool' is indeterminate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So in *Mary had a little lamb* - what is the *little lamb* if not a direct object?

Comment: @WS2 I've got an article whose whole thrust is that the notion of transitivity is poorly understood and definitions / diagnostics usually adjusted in dubious ways to try to deal with problem cases.

Comment: @WS2 revised comment: Have a look at [John Lawler's answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71892/passive-voice-for-quit/71904#71904).

Comment: @Suitcase - *Can a valid argument be made* -- I would encourage you to try to make one in an Answer.

Comment: The relation between a verb and its direct object is one of the most variable in the language. Subjects are usually agents or experiencers, and indirect objects are virtually always receivers, but direct objects can have arbitrary relations with their verb. They're governed by the verb, and that's why they're part of the Verb Phrase, unlike the subject; that's their syntactic definition. Semantically, they're all over the map.

Comment: There are also all kinds of problems, as Edwin points out, with variations on transitivity. Like measure verbs (_She weighs 50 kg_), denotational verbs (_They elected him treasurer_; _play_ is one), small verb plus nominalized extensions (_She lent a hand/gave a push/took a punch_), etc. I used to tell students that transitivity is a property of clauses, not of verbs; and that it comes in degrees -- it's not a matter of transitive or intransitive only.

Comment: *Play*, in this sense, means *portray*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, it is *not* a linking verb as you say.

The most common *linking verbs* are *'be'* and its other forms such as *am, was, will be* and so on. Linking verbs *do* describe the subject. And, the subject with linking verbs *don't* do any action.

Say,

> She *is* hungry - the linking verb 'is' *describes* her.

Now, action verbs are different. They *show* that the subjects do action.

Say,

> She *sings* nicely - the action verb *sing* describes her *action*.

Since you read here, tell me, what is the verb in your example?

> My younger sister ***played*** Tiny Tim in the Christmas performance.

So to answer this question is- no, it is *not* used as a linking verb. It's an *action verb.*

Comment: So *became* is not a linking verb? Or is there no action in *the kitten eventually became a cat*?

Answer (score 0):

*Played* is a transitive verb in your sentence with *Tiny Tim* as its object.